# Program will not let me store only the last three scores of the user

Tags: python, file, text, python-idle

```
if class_number == 0:
    #This will create and open a new text file under the name
    #of the class_tag variable.
    file = open("Class 0" + ".txt", "a")
    #This will write down the user's name and their score
    file.write(str(name) + " scored " + str(score))
    #This will create a new line for each user
    file.write("\n")
    #This will close the file.
    file.close()

import collections

def new3ElementDeque():
   return collections.deque([], 3)

nameTop3 = collections.defaultdict(new3ElementDeque)

with open("Class 0.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        user, score = line.split(':')
        nameTop3[name].append(score)
```

I tried to get the program to only save the last three scores of the user rather than all the scores into a text file.

**It looks like this now:**

```
student scored 3
student scored 8
student scored 0
student scored 4
student scored 10
student scored 3
student scored 0
student scored 4
```

**I want it to be like this:**

```
student scored 3
student scored 0
student scored 4
```

**However, the IDLE shell states:**

```
    name, score = line.split(':')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How would I get the program to store the last three scores of the user and save it to text file?

The name input is:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
```

Comment: looks like there is no ':' in the `line`, so when it tries to split it by ':', the result has only one element and you cannot assign `user` and `score` since there is only one element.

Comment: do a `print line` before `user, score = line.split(':')` and check that there is no ':'

Comment: Julien Spronck, how would I use 'print line'? Like this: 'print line user, score = line.split('scored')?

Comment: Can you show the input file?

Comment: Morb,                                                                                                      name = input("What is your name? ")

Comment: not that, the text file you are reading, `Class 0.txt`, or just a sample

Comment: I recommend you read through a python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: @Morb, 'code' student scored 3
student scored 8
student scored 0
student scored 4
student scored 10
student scored 3
student scored 0
student scored 4

Comment: If this is what you have in `Class 0.txt`, `split(":")` can't work

Answer (score 0):

There is no ':' in `line`, so when it tries to split it by ':', the result has only one element and you cannot assign user and score since there is only one element.

If all lines in your file are like 'blah scored x', you can replace the line `user, score = line.split(':')` by `user, score = line.split(' scored ')`

```
with open("Class 0.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        user, score = line.split(' scored ')
        nameTop3[user].append(score)
```

Comment: I updated my code and it worked at first, but when I did it again, it didn't work.

Comment: This came up:    name, score = line.split(' scored ')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Not all lines in your file are like 'blah scored x'. Type `print line` between the lines `for line in f:` and `name, score = line.split(' scored ')` and tell us what is printed on your screen right before the error message.

Comment: It says 'invalid syntax' before the whole program can start, because of 'line'.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "because of `line". Look at the code I just posted in my answer ... I don't think there is a syntax error in there ... is it what you tried?